# Handling 'choose a digital certificate' with selenium webdriver chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, python-2.7, certificate, webdriver

When I open a page with selenium webdriver I get a chrome dialog box "Choose certificate". The default certificate is the right one so I only have to click OK button. But I have problem with this. I have python code:

```
drv = webdriver.Chrome()   
drv.get("https://example.com/login")
```

and after that I want to do something like:

```
drv.switch_to_alert().accept()
```

or

```
drv.switch_to_alert().send_keys(Keys.TAB)
drv.switch_to_alert().send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
```

The problem is that the code stops executing on line drv.get("https://example.com/login"). Webdriver is waiting for page to load. And before that line there is no chrome dialog box.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use something like AutoIT:

http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Why you ask? It's an OS dialog, which Selenium does not and probably never will handle, so you'll have to turn to other solutions (in C# you should use native Win32 API methods to click the button for instance).

Comment: and what do you do on Linux?

Answer (score 3):

before handling anything here, add below so it will not get frozen as soon as you navigate/triggert the certificate pop up. remeber to add the correct waittime back later.

```
 getDriver().manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

after this, then you can try using keyboard or autoIt whatever .

Answer (score 3):

You can configure you Policys Group for Chrome choose your certificate.

Chrome use a registry with a json with information of your certificate. After you configure gpo,find a way to modified this json with Python.

With C# I use Microsoft.Win32.Registry to manipulates the registrys.

Follow the steps to configure you gpo:

First I need to thanks [IngussNeilands](https://gist.github.com/IngussNeilands) for the tutorial provided on his Github. It saved me!
You can follow the steps on IngussNeilands´s tutorial [here](https://gist.github.com/IngussNeilands/3bbbb7d78954c85e2e988cf3bfec7caa) or follow my version of his tutorial below.
## Steps to Configure the Policy Groups

1. Download Chrome Policy Tamplates from here: http://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chrome/policy/policy_templates.zip
2. Extract the `.zip` file and find the `chrome.adm` that matches the country and the language settings on your Windows, following the path: `policy_templates\windows\adm\<YourCountryAndLanguage>\chrome.adm`
3. Type `"run"` into your Windows Search Bar or press `Windows + R`. Then type de command `gpedit.msc` to open the *The Local Group Policy Editor*
4. Now, access: `'Computer Policy>> Computer Configuration'` and right-click the file `'Administrative Templates'` and select `'Add or remove tamplates'`
5. Click `'add'` and navigate to the `chrome.adm` that you choose before on  `'policy_templates\windows\adm\<YourCountryAndLanguage>\chrome.adm'`. Click to open it
6. Now, navigate to:
   `'Computer Policy>> Computer Configuration>> Administrative Templates>> Classic Administrative Templates(ADM)>> Google>> Google Chrome>> Content Settings'`
7. Then on the rigth side of the window find and double-click the option `'Automatically select client certificates for these sites'`
8. Click the `'Enabled'` option
9. Now, Click the `'Show...'` in the option pane below
10. Copy and paste the `'JSON'` below in the line of the column Value:
    `{"pattern":"https://[*.]example.com","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"example.com"}, "SUBJECT":{"CN":"value"}}`. This JSON needs to be rewriten with your certificate informations

### **How to rewrite the Chrome Configure JSON**

Ok, now a will give you a brief explanation on how to rewrite the Chrome Config JSON.

In the "pattern" key the value needs to be the URL that the certificate will be sent to. In most cases this URL is the same URL of the page, but some sites don´t use the same URL base to send the certificate.
For example, when I was trying to *webscraping* the NFS-e in Uberlândia city I needed to debug the script of the page to find the URL to where the certificate was sent.

The "filter" key will have the certificate information. In my case, I need to access the same website with diferent certificates, for that I'll have to fill the JSON with the information of "ISSUER" and "SUBJECT". Chrome will choose one certificate that matches with the informations content in the filter key. For example, if I fill the "CN" from "ISSUER" object with "SERASA Certificadora Digital v5" I'll have more than one certificate with these informations and Chrome won´t be able to choose the right certificate.

In my git in [here](https://github.com/JimmyelsonSilvaPeres/AcessWithCertifiedChromeCSharp) you can find the solution to alter the JSON for access the same site with more the one certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Certificates are managed by the OS, not the browser. Delete all but the necessary certificate from your browser's certificate store and then configure the browser to automatically select the certificate when only one certificate is present. You could also create a browser profile and have your program launch this profile or avoid testing over HTTPS.

Comment: how do you configure chrome to accept the default certificate without asking?