# How to click OK on a dialog box with Selenium?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I wrote a script to log on to a web page.  Before even showing the page Chrome asks me to choose a certificate.  How do I press the OK button?

[image]

Here is what I have so far...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://blah.blah.com")
```

However, the last line does not finish until I (manually) click the button.  There is only one certificate.  How do I click **OK** programmatically?

[image]

Comment: Is that alert dialog?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling 'choose a digital certificate' with selenium webdriver chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960084/handling-choose-a-digital-certificate-with-selenium-webdriver-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to select a certificate you need to know that Selenium can´t do this.

This popup is come from Windows.

I answered a question like that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960084/handling-choose-a-digital-certificate-with-selenium-webdriver-chrome) where i explain how can you config your Group Policy to made chrome choose the certificate for you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a alert box,

You can try, `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();`
This will switch to alert and click on OK button.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to interact with pop-ups. Try to disable such windows: https://superuser.com/a/41937

Answer (score 0):

try below line in Your Script

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
       alert.accept();
       alert.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following within your script:
driver.switch_to_alert().accept()