# Select a Certificate - Selenium - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a simple script to automatize the access in a platform with SSL Certificate, when i navigate in the url, the browser opens the popup for selecting the certificate, as shown in the photo.

[image]

Im using this portion of code to interact with the popup, but nothing happens.

`alert_obj = driver.switch_to_alert().accept()`

I can't interact with the window, I would like to give it the OK input.

Any hint?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the html code of the pop-up window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling 'choose a digital certificate' with selenium webdriver chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960084/handling-choose-a-digital-certificate-with-selenium-webdriver-chrome)

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out?