# How to select specific certificate with Selenium in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So, I'm having a problem selecting a certificate with Selenium in Python. I've tried to select accepting it as if it were an alert, but without success. Could someone help me?
[Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHUvO.png)
Here's an example of my driver settings.

```
    options = Options()
    if self.invisivel:
        options.add_argument('headless')
        options.add_argument('--log-level=3')

    prefs = {"download.default_directory": self.diretorio}
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

    self.dc = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    self.dc['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}

    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")

    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options,
                                   desired_capabilities=self.dc)

    stealth(self.driver,
            user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36',
            languages=["en-US", "en"],
            vendor="Google Inc.",
            platform="Win32",
            webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
            renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
            fix_hairline=True,
            )
```

Comment: I believe this is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960084/handling-choose-a-digital-certificate-with-selenium-webdriver-chrome).

Comment: This worked, but when I put headless argument it doesn't work.

Comment: What's the error message ? Typically with headless mode. You need to define the screen size instead of using the default one.  And it is common to run it with additional flag likes ```--no-sandbox``` and ```--disable-gpu```

Comment: it does not return an error, I am informing in add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to accept the allert, right?
This should work:

```py
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Comment: Unsuccessful, it does not behave the same as an alert.

Comment: Well, we need to debug this.